Are there any (free) software for Kleinian groups, plotting and calculations.?
Is there any free or commersial software package, for windows and with an easy to use interface, for plotting and calculations on Kleinian groups? In particular, I would like it to be able to plot out limit sets and manipulate Möbius functions (I am not very good at programming, otherwise I could have tried to code the algorithms  in "Indra's Pearls").
I took a peak at the resource page for Indra's Pearls (http://klein.math.okstate.edu/IndrasPearls/) but it seems the programs there use Maple?
